# Why isn't toLowerCase being applied to every word in the following replace chain?

Tags: javascript

I want to turn this: `livingRoom` into this `Living room`:

So as a first step I want to break the camel case word and turn every word to lowercase:

```
"livingRoom"
  .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
  .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toLowerCase(); })
```

However, I get this:

```
// => "living Room"
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: After the first replace you could just do `.toLowerCase()`. Or replace `/^./` with `/^.+$/` so it matches the entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
"livingRoom"
  .replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str){ return ' '+ str.toLowerCase(); })
  .replace(/^.?/, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
//"Living room"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What's the use of the `?` in the last regex?

Comment: @alex, `n?` matches any string that contains zero or one occurrences of n, [more about JS regexp quantifiers](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: You answer should explain what the OPs issue is and how your answer fixes it. Otherwise the OP has to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

`/^./` only matches the first character, "l", which is already lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You have,

```
// This replace 'R' in 'livingRoom' with space + group1, which is ' R'.
.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1') // Returns 'living Room'

// This finds any character after the beginning of line. which is 'l'.
.replace(/^./, function (str) { return str.toLowerCase() }); // str is 'l'
```

However, there's another easy way to approach "Living room", as for example.

```
var str = "livingRoom"
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');

// str is now 'living Room'
// Uppercase the first char in str, and concat it with the lowercased rest.
str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
// str is now 'Living room'
```

Comment: What is $1 in 1st statement?

Comment: @EvaMariam It's group1. In his case, group1 is any letter from uppercase A to Z.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("livingRoom"
  .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
  .replace(/ [A-Z]/, function(str){ return str.toLowerCase(); })
  .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); }));
```

^. just replaces the first character